# Is there any functions like REPT and UNICHAR in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is there any functions like REPT and UNICHAR in Tableau..

REPT and UNICHAR are available in Microsoft Excel.

Is there any way to replicate the same functionality in Tableau ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple steps.

First use the **SPACE**() function to create a string of spaces of a length of your choosing, i.e., SPACE(SUM(Employees)) creates a string with one space per employee.

Then use **REPLACE**() to convert each space into the desired replicated string.

So `replace(space(N), " ", "TEXT")` creates N back to back copies of "TEXT"

Comment: there's a syntax error and logical error- remove the last parenthesis and replace space instead of null.. so working formula is:  `replace(space(N), " ", "TEXT")` .. couldn't edit answer due to less than 6 chars to correct :P

Comment: fixed the typos. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From a [post](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2014/06/string-calculations-in-tableau.html) I found with a quick google (2015):

> unlike Excel, Tableau does not have a REPT function to repeat texts.
>
> However, if the maximum number of repetitions is limited (let's say
>   5), you can build your own function with a CASE statement and simple
>   string concatenations.
>
> Let's say [Text] is the text to repeat and [N] is the parameter
>   defining how often the text shall be repeated. The Calculated Field
>   would look like this:

```
CASE [N] 
WHEN 1 THEN [Text]
WHEN 2 THEN [Text]+[Text]
WHEN 3 THEN [Text]+[Text]+[Text]
WHEN 4 THEN [Text]+[Text]+[Text]+[Text]
WHEN 5 THEN [Text]+[Text]+[Text]+[Text]+[Text]
END
```

> Agreed, not really an elegant solution, but I do not see another way
>   to do this in a Calculated Field in Tableau.

As for the `UNICHAR`, I only know of the similar `CHAR` but this is of course limited to ASCII only.

If you really need the functionality as in Excel, what you could do is call an R function which implements the same behavior. This is done by creating a calculated field that invokes the R engine. More information on that on the Tableau website and their [whitepaper](https://www.tableau.com/learn/whitepapers/using-r-and-tableau)